# multiply two non-na matrices in R, result is all-NA

Tags: r, matrix-multiplication, na

I have two matrices, A and B.

```
sum(is.na(A)) = 0
sum(is.na(B)) = 0
```

but when I multiply them, the result (a 45x1 matrix) is all NA

```
sum(is.na(A%*%B)) = 45
```

Any ideas?  I will work on uploading the data now, so people can reproduce if they're interested.

Comment: Hard to say without data.  The only clue I can think of is `is.na(Inf)` (FALSE); `is.na(0)` (FALSE); `is.na(Inf*0)` (TRUE). `summary(c(A))`; `summary(c(B))` might provide a lot of clues even without full data.

Comment: A = B = matrix(1:9, nrow=3);
  
sum(is.na(A)) # 0  ;

sum(is.na(B)) # 0  ;

sum(is.na(A%*%B)) # equals 0;